# HTML Session data isn't saving and unwantly clears page

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

So i can save one question but when i add more it doesnt work. I though i could just add on to postquestion function copy and paste and just change 16 to 15 but i guess that is to easy
I need to save about 16 total questions with 4 choices each question, and the selected radio is the correct answer.
Also is there a way to save selected radio buttons into session and local storage?

```js
function postQuestion() {
    var obj = {
      question: document.getElementById("question16").value,
      choice62: document.getElementById("choice62").value,
      choice63: document.getElementById("choice63").value,
      choice64: document.getElementById("choice64").value,
      choice65: document.getElementById("choice65").value
    }

    try {
      sessionStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(obj));
    } catch (error) {
      alert("Enable Session storage");
    }
    
    return false;
}

function PreviewImage16() {

   var oFReader = new FileReader();
   oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage16").files[0]);
   
    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
      document.getElementById("uploadPreview16").src = oFREvent.target.result;
      sessionStorage.setItem("image", oFREvent.target.result);
    };
};
```

```html
<div>
    Enter Question 16:
    <input type="text" id="question16" name="question16">
    <br>
    <br> Next, add a correct answer and several incorrect answers for your question.
    <br>
    <form onsubmit="return postQuestion()">
      <p>
        <input type="radio" name="choice62" value="62">
        <label>
          <input id="choice62" size="50">
        </label>
      </p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="choice63" value="63">
      <label>
        <input id="choice63" size="50">
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="choice64" value="64">
      <label>
        <input id="choice64" size="50">
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="choice65" value="65">
      <label>
        <input id="choice65" size="50">
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
    </p>
    <br>
    <img id="uploadPreview16" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" />
    <input id="uploadImage16" type="file" name="myPhoto16" onchange="PreviewImage16();" />
</div>
```

Comment: There's an awful lot wrong with your code -- none of your text boxes have a `name` attribute and all radio buttons in a group must have the same value for the `name` attribute to make them mutually exclusive. In fact, why do you even have radio buttons? Just identify the first textbox as the one that requires the correct answer and the remaining ones are incorrect answers. What purpose do the radio buttons serve?

Comment: What you said about the radio button makes sense. Im little confuse about the text boxes not having any a name attribute, wouldnt name="question16" be the attribute

Comment: That's your first text box. None of the others have a `name`.